# regex to match first space looking back from an = sign

Tags: regex

I have a text like the below:

`<p style="color: blue;" data="something">`

I want to get `style` and `data` but `/(?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\=)/g` matches `style` and `blue;" data`.

Essentially, I want to only match the text between the first space and `=`

What am I missing? Can someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\S+(?==)
[^\s=]+(?==)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kn9y3o/1).

*Details*:

- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars (even including `=` chars)
- `[^\s=]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and `=` chars
- `(?==)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `=` char to appear immediately to the right of the current location.